# How can I use a `rustc` crate?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to use a `rustc` crate in my program.

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate rustc;
extern crate rustc_typeck;
extern crate syntax;
extern crate syntax_pos;

use rustc::hir;

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, World!");

}
```

I also added an extra dependency in the *Cargo.toml* file:

```
[dependencies]
log = "0.4.1"
```

`cargo run` emits a bunch of errors that it's private and nightly only:

```
error: use of unstable library feature 'rustc_private': this crate is being loaded from the sysroot, an unstable location; did you mean to load this crate from crates.io via `Cargo.toml` instead? (see issue #27812)
 --> src/main.rs:2:1
  |
2 | extern crate rustc;
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

It seems Cargo want a stable crate from `crates.io`, but I don't know which crate I should use. There's no crate named `rustc` on `crates.io`.

Here's my Rust installation version.

- rustc 1.23.0 (766bd11c8 2018-01-01)
- cargo 0.24.0 (45043115c 2017-12-05)

I installed it using `rustup`.

How can I use a `rustc` crate for my program?

---

I tried to add `rustc = "1.23.0"` to `Cargo.toml`, but it still doesn't work with this error:

```
error: no matching package named `rustc` found (required by `rust-swift-serde-gen`)
```

Comment: Isn't this asking for you to declare `rustc` in your `Cargo.toml`?

Comment: @tadman I'm not sure. How should I do that? Can you post an answer? I couldn't find a crate page for the `rustc` crate on `crates.io`.

Comment: I mean add it to `Cargo.toml` to pull down that dependency instead of using the private one that ships with Rust. Just add that line and try it!

Comment: @tadman It doesn't work. `error: no matching package named \`rustc\` found (required by \`rust-swift-serde-gen\`)`...  So sad.

Comment: I added `rustc = "1.23.0"`.

Comment: Guess it's time to open the magical mystery box that is issue #27812.

Comment: @tadman Okay. I'm gonna check it out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`rustc` is indeed not published on crates.io.

Because the API for the `rustc` crate is not stable, you must switch to the nightly compiler and opt in by adding this line at the beginning of your crate root (`main.rs` or `lib.rs`):

```
#![feature(rustc_private)]
```

Naturally, since the API is not stable, every time you update your nightly compiler, things may break without warning!

Comment: Ah... sounds like there will be no stable `rustc` crate forever.

Comment: Definitely true! This seems like an XY problem though: What do you want to use `rustc` for? There might be a stable way of achieving that, given that depending on `rustc` itself as a library will never be stable.

Comment: @daboross I'd like to extract DTO(serializable objects) schema from Rust source code, and make a code generator for another language (e.g. Swift). It's okay if this code work only on latest stable Rust compiler, but dependency to nightly seems to be an overkill for daily use... I think here's some missing link...

Comment: It seems what I have to make is a compiler plugin rather than a independent program.

Comment: Ah, cool! It might be a bit more work but I'd recommend making a library for use in build scripts and parsing source using the [syn](https://github.com/dtolnay/syn) crate. I think making a source-parsing plugin deserves a question of its own though here on SO if you'd be willing to make one and link it.

Comment: @daboross Recently I restarted this work, and I finally discovered that I need type resolution - so analysis stage. Would `syn` provide fully resolved type info?

Comment: Unfortunately it won't, it just parses syntax into an AST. I'm not sure what you'll need to do type resolution at/before compile time, but either hooking into rustc as a plugin or using it as a library is probably a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

### Method 1: use the *rustc-dev* component

```
rustup component add rustc-dev
```

Then you can use:

```
#![feature(rustc_private)]
extern crate rustc_ast;
```

### Method 2: use rustc-ap-rustc_* crates

According to the [rustc-auto-publish](https://github.com/alexcrichton/rustc-auto-publish) repository:

*crate rustc-ap-rustc_ast* is the same as *rustc_ast* in the Rust source code.

*racer* and *rust-analyzer* use rustc-ap-rustc_* crates.

Here is some code from racer's *Cargo.toml* file:

```
[dependencies.rustc_errors]
package = "rustc-ap-rustc_errors"
version = "712.0.0"

[dependencies.rustc_parse]
package = "rustc-ap-rustc_parse"
version = "712.0.0"

[dependencies.rustc_session]
package = "rustc-ap-rustc_session"
version = "712.0.0"
```